# Reorder bars in geom_bar by multiple factors

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I want my plot to be ordered by its highest column value, but for more than one variable: first for vs, then s, then us and within for its values. I.e. first bar shows ID 14 with 2 counts in VS then ID 10, then ID 16 (because 10 has a higher value for S than 16).
I've came across the reorder function. But my code does not even reorder for one value...

```
# use data from library(MM) and melt
data(wilson, package = "MM")
non_met <- as.data.frame(non_met)
non_met$ID <- seq(1,nrow(non_met))
mhouse <- melt(non_met, id=c("ID"))

ggplot(mhouse, aes(x=reorder(ID, -value), y=value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", lwd=0.5, color="white")
```

Next I tried to change my factor but that just inverts the colouring

```
mhouse$variable <- factor(mhouse$variable, levels=c("VS","S","US"))
head(mhouse[order(mhouse$variable, -mhouse$value),])

#   ID variable value
#50 14       VS     2
#45  9       VS     1
#46 10       VS     1
#52 16       VS     1
#37  1       VS     0
#38  2       VS     0
```

(still not quite the right order)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, here's one solution:

```
data(wilson, package = "MM")
non_met <- as.data.frame(non_met)
non_met$ID <- seq(1,nrow(non_met))
non_met <- non_met[order(-non_met$VS, -non_met$S, -non_met$US),]
non_met$order <- seq(1,nrow(non_met))
mhouse <- melt(non_met, id=c("ID", "order"))

ggplot(mhouse, aes(x=reorder(ID, order), y=value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", lwd=0.5, color="white")
```

but I'm open to any other idea about that problem